# Analog circuit for obtaining a phase shift of 1-2 s in an arterial pulse wave signal of period 1-2 Hz

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, pulse, phase-shift

I am trying to design an analog circuit using an operational amplifier to introduce a phase lag of the order of 1-2 seconds in an arterial pulse wave signal (photoplethysmogram or PPG for short) that has a period in the range of 1-2 Hz.

I simulated the above signal with 2 sine waves in LT Spice. Then, I used a simple phase lag circuit found on the internet to accomplish the phase shift or delay.

Please see attached images of the simulated circuit and my output plots.

R6 is the resistor I am varying to obtain the phase shifting. If R6 ~ 30K, I do get a phase shift of about 120 mS between PPG1 & PPG2 and the shifted signal PPG2 look realistic. However, since my requirement for phase lag is about 1-2 s, I increase R6 to = 330K. At this stage, I do not see any apparent phase shift between PPG1 & PPG2. Rather, I start to see mirroring. Also, at R6 ~ 100K, I see a distorted signal output at PPG2.

Am I doing something wrong here? Could you please advise any efficient solution(s)?

Thank you!

Sincerely,

Saif
[image]

Comment: Your signal consists of multiple frequencies; it's not just a single harmonic oscillator (ie., it's not a cosine). So, your circuit shifts these frequency components by different amounts. That is fair, that's exactly what the phase response of a system tells us

Comment: A second is really a long time when you need to have a phase shifter that works on a full octave (i.e. a frequency range where the highest frequency is at least twice as high as the lowest). This is usually not done in analog technology at all. Is there any reason you're trying to do this in analog circuitry? That's very hard!

Comment: Thanks for your messages Marcus! Actually, I over smooth this signal using a LPF of 0.2 Hz. Then I subtract the over smoothed signal from the pulse data to de-trend signal. The over smoothed signal is lagging by about 1 s. So for effective de-trending, the over smooth and actual pulse signals should be in phase. That’s why I try to introduce an equivalent phase lag (~ 1 s) in the pulse.

Comment: @Saif This doesn't look like a well thought out design to me. What papers have you read on the topic? For example, there is [this open source article](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1361-6579/ac826d) on *Detecting beats in the photoplethysmogram*. Also, [this paper](https://www.mdpi.com/1999-4893/5/4/588) on *An Efficient Algorithm for Automatic
Peak Detection in Noisy Periodic and Quasi-Periodic Signals* which also comes with this [github](https://github.com/LucaCerina/ampdLib) of source code. Just to name a couple. None seem to suggest your LPF.

Comment: Analogue delay of one second? There were bucket brigade chips in the 1980s but nobody does that any more.  can you get what you want bu predicting the trigger using a phase locked loop. or do it in software instead?

Comment: Be clear whether you are talking about 'time delay', which is appropraite for a signal with a range of frequencies, or 'phase shift', which is appropriate for a signal of a single frequency, or 'low pass filtering', which is again correct for a range of frequencies. The first is hard to do with analogue, people use digital methods. The second and third are easy.

Comment: @saif that is not how the math works out. If you want to build a high-pass filter (which is what you detrending is) out of a low-filter, you need to delay every frequency by exactly the same amount as it was delayed by the LPF. And since you've built that as analog filter (I guess), the delay is very frequency-dependent. So, you'd need to build an analog filter that has the same phase response as your LPF to compensate the phase response of your LPF. Instead, build a HPF right away, and honestly, build it in software. There's no reason to do this in analog circuitry to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

I recognize it isn't how you are currently approaching the problem, but the simplest approach might well be a simple microcontroller combined with an ADC and a DAC.

Very easy to write a loop which samples your data at say 100Hz, buffers 1-2s of samples, then starts playing out the data.  With appropriate input and output filtering should give you exactly what you are seeking.